# Linker error when wrapping a call to std::bind

Tags: c++, callback, linker-errors, stdbind

I am trying to save callbacks for later use in a class and run into the problem that the linker apparently can't see all the symbols it needs. The callbacks are member-functions of another object. If i hand a std::function over to the method registering the callback everything works fine. If I try to move the call to std::bind into the method and only pass the arguments to std::bind I get LNK2019 on MSVC2019.

The Class that stores the callbacks looks like this:
Class1.h

```
#ifndef CLASS1_H
#define CLASS1_H


#include <functional>
#include <string_view>

class Class1
{
public:
    using Callback_t = std::function<void(std::string_view)>;
    Class1();
    template<typename T>
    void addCallback(T * obj, void (T::*func)(std::string_view));
    void addCallback(Callback_t callback);
    void doStuff(std::string_view text);

private:
    Callback_t m_callback;
};

#endif // CLASS1_H
```

Class1.cpp

```
#include "Class1.h"

Class1::Class1()
{

}

template<typename T>
void Class1::addCallback(T * obj, void (T::*func)(std::string_view))
{
    m_callback = std::bind(func, obj, std::placeholders::_1);
}

void Class1::addCallback(Callback_t callback)
{
    m_callback = callback;
}

void Class1::doStuff(std::string_view text)
{
    m_callback(text);
}
```

The object of which I take the callback looks like this:
Class2.h

```
#ifndef CLASS2_H
#define CLASS2_H

#include <string_view>


class Class2
{
public:
    Class2();
    void display(std::string_view text);
};

#endif // CLASS2_H
```

Class2.cpp

```
#include "Class2.h"
#include <iostream>
Class2::Class2()
{

}

void Class2::display(std::string_view text)
{
    std::cout << "The text was: " << text << std::endl;
}
```

The classes are both used from this file.
main.cpp

```
#include "Class1.h"
#include "Class2.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    Class1 obj1;
    Class2 obj2;

    obj1.addCallback(&obj2, &Class2::display); //results in linker error

    obj1.addCallback(std::bind(&Class2::display, &obj2, std::placeholders::_1)); //works

    obj1.doStuff("wallalalalalalla!!!!");
}
```

Is there any solution to achive the call that only uses the pointer to the object and the pointer-to-member-function instead of the std::function?

Comment: Please show the full text of the error